# How to convert several rows to columns in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Let's say I have this in Notepad++:

```
CHARGE_ID   LAST_MODIFIED   CHARGE  PROPORTION  CURRENCY_ID ACCOUNT_ID
2194703831  28-06-2016 11:44:02 2.49    1   95000060    590511
```

I would like to convert it like that:

```
CHARGE_ID: 2194703831
LAST_MODIFIED: 28-06-2016 11:44:02
CHARGE: 2.49
PROPORTION: 1
CURRENCY_ID: 95000060
ACCOUNT_ID: 590511
```

Comment: do you have only two rows to transform or there are multiple? Are items separated by tab characters or by spaces (is it fixed with)?

Comment: It could be more. But for now two rows is OK. Yes, they are separated by tab character

Comment: I don't know the info for your situation, but I'm sure someone good with regular expressions could go into Search -> Find -> Replace -> Check regular expression in down direction and fill out the Find what: and replace with: fields with a possible solution

Answer (score 4):

You need to choose right tool for the job. Use Excel to help you with your text file. Inside the Excel:

1. Use **Text import wizard** (menu **Data** > **From Text**) to import values into cells.
2. Select imported cells (as rectangular selection) and use **Copy**.
3. Use **Paste Special** with **Transpose** option to flip rows and columns (this is what you requested).
4. Paste the result back to text file.

Answer (score 1):

##### Use Regular Expression (REGEX)

1. Open Find (CTRL+F)
2. Make sure within the "Search Mode", the "Regular expression" is checked [o]
3. Paste the below line in "FIND" box

```
^([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\r\n^([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\r\n\r\n
```

4. Paste the below line in "REPLACE" box

```
$1: $7\r\n$2: $8\r\n$3: $9\r\n$4: $10\r\n$5: $11\r\n$6: $12\r\n \r\n
```

```
^        = From the start of line
([^\t]+) = All those which are not a TAB char.
\t       = Followed by a TAB char.
\r\n     = New Line / Linefeed / End of line char  
$1,$2....= Refers to the position of ([^\t]+) in the FIND
```

**NOTE:** I added extra `\r\n\r\n` at the end of REPLACE as I thought you might want to separate multiple sets of records.

Comment: I don't think you want to include email here, especially in non-obfuscated form, unless you like spam.

Comment: Removed email address.